# Managed Instance Restart

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

Does anyone know how to restart a SQL Server Managed Instance?

The stop / start / reset are all grayed out, so that’s really. It an option.

Any thoughts?

Thanks...

Comment: Are you having a problem that you think an Instance restart would solve? There might be a more surgical fix, so additional background on why might help

Answer (score 6):

You don't restart Managed Instance. The beauty of PaaS is that the cloud service provider ensures that you get a certain uptime SLA-- 99.99% in this case.

The service is abstracted away. Microsoft will ensure that the service is "always" up and running. They handle patching and maintenance on the OS and the instance (and necessary restarts that go along with those things).

If you need to stop, scale, or make other changes to the instance, you'd do that from the Azure portal (either the web GUI or PowerShell).

Comment: AMTwo, I would love to go with that answer, but the problem is that I need to reset TempDB. By default, for some reason, it was set to autogrow in 8 MB chunks. Now that it's over 1 TB in size, anything that uses tempdb is amazingly slow because of all of the VLFs.

Comment: And I've tried restarting from the Azure portal itself, but I either don't have permissions or it's just not there.

Comment: Scaling the instance sometimes (or perhaps always) restarts.  If that doesn't work, moving between Gen4 and Gen5, or between Business Critical and Standard will always require a restart as the hardware is different between Gen4 and Gen5, and the storage is different between Business Critical and Standard.

Answer (score 0):

We have used this command successfully in the past to bounce a Managed Instance when we were having issues with Full Text.  We have tested it on both a system that's part of a failover group as well as one that is not.  It kept the "primary" in the same datacenter, so it's not doing a failover in the sense of moving from one failover node to another.

Unfortunately, the documentation is .. sparse so I'm theorizing here.  But I think what it does is tell the Managed Instance to move from the current processing node to another one, but keep it in the same region.  I don't know if it will do anything with tempdb or not (my guess is that it will cause it to rebuild tempdb), but I know that it did resolve our issue with the full text daemon.

So, your mileage may vary and use at your own risk.

```
Invoke-AzSqlInstanceFailover -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -Name "ManagedInstance01"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/invoke-azsqlinstancefailover?view=azps-10.1.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-6.2.1